# Переполнение стека при работе с реестром

Tags: delphi, реестр

Здравствуйте!

Почему когда я далаю прогон по всему реестру (просматриваю все ключи), в один момент программа просто вылетает и всё... Подобное происходит и на других машинах. Происходит это именно тогда, когда путь достигает `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Class`. И при чём, постоянно на одном и том же ключе, но если этот ключ удалить, то такая же фигня произойдёт на следующем... и это случается только в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, в остальных разделах всё нормально. Вот такая запарка!

Вот моя процедура:

```
procedure FullRegScan(HK: HKEY; RegPath: string);
 var Reg: TRegistry;
 i: Integer;
 l, val: TStrings;
 Root, s: string;
 begin
 Reg:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_ALL_ACCESS);
 case HK of
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT : Root:= 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT';
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER : Root:= 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER';
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE : Root:= 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE';
 HKEY_USERS : Root:= 'HKEY_USERS';
 HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG : Root:= 'HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG';
 end;
 Reg.RootKey:= HK;
 Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(RegPath);
 val:= TStringList.Create;
 Reg.GetValueNames(val);
 l:= TStringList.Create;
 Reg.GetKeyNames(l);
 /////////////////////////////////////////
 s:= Reg.CurrentPath;
 /////////////////////////////////////////
 Reg.CloseKey;
 for i:= 0 to l.Count - 1 do
 begin
 if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(s + '\' + l.Strings[i]) then
 begin
 Form1.lbl1.Caption:= '[' + Root + '\' + Reg.CurrentPath + ']';
 try
 FullRegScan(HK , Reg.CurrentPath);
 except
 end;
 end;
 Reg.CloseKey;
 Application.ProcessMessages;
 end;
 l.Free;
 val.Free;
 Reg.Free;
 end;
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня была подобная проблема, джве недели с ней бодался, решилось удалением ключей HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*, теперь работает как чесы.

Comment: А винду снести не проще?

Comment: > решилось удалением ключей HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*.
Что вообще всех?

Comment: аботает как **чесы** - "верю"

Answer (score 0):

Или убирайте рекурсию, или увеличивайте стек. И надо ли на каждом уровне рекурсии создавать свой TRegistry?